# IntelliJ showing code changes (Git)

Tags: java, git, scala, intellij-idea

When I make code changes in IntelliJ, the IDE will show me which lines I've added/modified by color-coding next to the line number.

[image]

However, when I commit my changes (git commit ...), then the helpful color-coding disappears. Is there any way to still show the line changes even after I commit them?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The whole point of the highlighting is to see what you've changed since your last commit.

Comment: Do not turn it off. Your later you will thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not 'color' solution but if you right-click on left (might be a line number) and select **annotate** then you will see some details about git changes in whole file:

[image]
If you click on one of them then more info will popup:
[image]